# Split a string and assign to a class object in vb.net

Tags: string, vb.net

I am trying to split a string assign the values to a class object.

My string looks like following:

```
1-|@$@|-TEST1-|@$@|-Yes|||2-|@$@|-TEST2-|@$@|-No|||3-|@$@|-TEST3-|@$@|-Yes|||
```

I want to split the above each string with delimiter as `-|@$@|-` and assign it my class object.My class looks like following:

```
Public Class Employee
   Public Property EmpId As Integer
   Public Property Name as String
   Public Property Value as Boolean
End Class
```

So i want to assign each value from the splitted string to the object of above class.

So it should be like this:

```
EmpId = 1
Name = TEST1
Value = True(Or yes Or 1)
```

I want to loop it and assign all the 3 Emps(TEST1, TEST2, TEST3) to a list or a single Emp Object.

I am trying to split like following:

```
Dim myString As String = "1-|@$@|-TEST1-|@$@|-Yes|||2-|@$@|-TEST2-|@$@|-No|||3-|@$@|-TEST3-|@$@|-Yes|||"
Dim delimiter As Char = "-|@$@|-"

Dim subStrings() As String = myString.Split(delimiter)
For Each substring In subStrings
        //assign here
Next
```

But I am unable to split it as expected.

Any help?  I can modify the delimiter and necessary changes to the string to make it easy and efficient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you unable to split it as expected?  What obstacle prevents you from completing your task?

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags.

Comment: Comment removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use Regex expresions, folow the next example:

```
        Dim myString As String = "1-|@$@|-TEST1-|@$@|-Yes|||2-|@$@|-TEST2-|@$@|-No|||3-|@$@|-TEST3-|@$@|-Yes|||"


        Dim objects = Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(myString, "\|\|\|", Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        Dim lst As List(Of Employee) = New List(Of Employee)

        For Each k In objects
            If k.Trim <> "" Then
                Dim props = Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(k, "-\|\@\$\@\|-", Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                lst.Add(New Employee() With {.EmpId = props(0), .Name = props(1), .Value = If(props(2) = "Yes", True, False)})
            End If
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("{0,10} {1,10} {2,10}", "Id", "Value", "Name")

        lst.ForEach(New Action(Of Employee)(Sub(t)
                                                Console.WriteLine("{0,10} {1,10} {2,10}", t.EmpId, t.Value, t.Name)
                                            End Sub))

        Console.ReadLine()
```

if you see, i use two splits, first for "|||" then for "-|@$@|-".
i runing this code on a console application and work fine.

Comment: Can you explain me why we need to use two splits?

Comment: First for split the objects, then for split the properties

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare delimiter as an Array. You should really be declaring it as an Array of String, to take advantage of the correct overload.

```
Dim delimiter As String= New String() {"-|@$@|-"}
```

Currently what is happening is the value of delimiter is being set to '-', the first character of the string it is being assigned from. This is causing you to split on dashes instead of your expected substring.

You can fully populate your employee collection with the following LINQ expression:

```
Dim employees = 
    From employeeRows In myString.Split(New String() {"|||"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    Let employeeValues = employeeRows.Split(New String() {"-|@$@|-"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    Where Not employeeValues.Any(Function(x) String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
    Select New Employee With{
            .EmpId = Integer.Parse(employeeValues(0)),
            .Name = employeeValues(1),
            .Value = If(employeeValues(2) = "Yes", True, False)
            }
```

Comment: Can you please help me in assigning the substring value(after split) to my class object. I am not sure how to loop each time and add it a 3 list items or type myObject(object of Employee)

Comment: @Santosh Add an outer loop where you split on "|||" first (ie, splitting into the individual employees) then assign the employee properties within an inner loop, after you split on "-|@$@|-". Basically, split the string into employees, then split the employees to values, then assign the values to an employee object and add it to a list.

Comment: Sorry, Didn't get much. I did in similar way but wasn't showing up as expected. Can you please add it to the answer.

Comment: @Santosh I've updated the answer with an example expression for mapping and some improvements on how the String Split works with strings in VB.NET.